# $\phi(x+1)=\phi(x)$ and $\phi(\frac{x}{2})\phi(\frac{x+1}{2}) =d\phi(x)$ then $\phi$ is constant

Tags: real-analysis, special-functions

For $0 < x < \infty$, let $\phi(x)$ be positive and continuously twice differentiable satisfying $\phi(x+1)=\phi(x)$ and $\phi(\frac{x}{2})\phi(\frac{x+1}{2}) =d\phi(x)$ with $d$ being a constant.

I have to show that $\phi$ is constant, but I don't know how to start the proof here. Any hints?

Answer (score 0):

Iterating the second condition one you get
\begin{align*}
\phi\left(\frac x2\right)\phi\left(\frac{x+1}2\right)
&\phi\left(\frac{x+2}2\right)\phi\left(\frac{x+3}2\right)
\cdots\phi\left(\frac{x+2n}2\right)\phi\left(\frac{x+2n+1}2\right)\\
&=d^n\phi(x)\phi(x-2)\cdots\phi(x-2n)\\
&=d^n\left(\phi(x)\right)^n
\end{align*}
where the last equality follows from the first condition on $\phi$.

Can you conclude from here?

Comment: How does this help? The first product simplifies to $\phi(x/2)^n\phi(x/2 +1/2)^n$ so isn't this is just a complicated way of restating the original condition.

Comment: I would guess the direction would be to look at the derivatives and see somehow that $\phi'(x)=0$ hence $\phi$ constant. Is that right or is this the wrong path?

Answer (score -1):

This question is somehow interesting, as for $\phi$ is not a positive function, you can always find a solution of form :
$\phi(x)= ce^{ i2\pi x}$
To solve it in case, I'll assume $d=1$ and $\phi$ is also continuous at $0$( Note that this function is 1-periodic)
Define $h$ as $h(x)=ln(\phi(x))$
So we have easily that:
$h(x)= h(\frac{x}{2})+h( \frac{x+1}{2})$
Which leads to, by induction,:
$ h(x) = \left( \sum_{k=0}^{2^n-1} h \left( \frac{x}{2^n}+\frac{k}{2^n}\right)\right)$
So,
$  h'(x)=\frac{1}{2^n}\left( \sum_{k=0}^{2^n-1} h' \left( \frac{x}{2^n}+\frac{k}{2^n}\right)\right) \longrightarrow h(1)-h(0)$ when $n \rightarrow \infty$ (Because h is continuous)
So $h'(x)=0$
QED.

Comment: Thanks for answer! So $h(x)=i2\pi xC$ with some constant C? But then $h(x)=h(\frac{x}{2})+h(\frac{x+1}{2})$ would be $2i\pi x+1$. Also how did you get the summation?

Comment: Well, in the complex case, it is a different thing, you can't even get the log right most of times. I don't check my solution for the complex case.

Comment: In the positive case, we only have constant as the solution.

Comment: I actually wasnt talking about complex case. Just trying to see why the h(x) can be represented in both ways

Comment: If that is your goal, then I must say your calculation is not true. As when h(x)= 2\pi x+c. The latter equation gives $c= \pi$

Comment: So ...,my solution is correct then?

Comment: so you mean $\phi(x)=ce^{2\pi x}$ without the i?

Comment: also you ar elooking at a particular solution for $\phi$. there can be other or no?